# How to interpolate non linearly missing data in time series taking account the past?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, interpolation, missing-data

I am working with **time series with missing data**. The time series is only **ascending**. It is **hourly** time series.

I woud like to **interpolate** the missing data in taking account the **past** values. The interpolation **shouldn't be linear**.

I am working with Python and Pandas. I used the following method:

```
data.interpolate(method="time",limit_area="inside")
```

This is the result applied to one of my time series:

[image]

The interpolation is in blue. However, we can see it is linear which is not what I expect. I tried to **resample** hourly data to daily data but still it doesn't work.

Is there another method which can **interpolate missing data in a time series taking account the past values** (past trend)?

Thank you.

Comment: There is a large number of different interpolation algorithms, which might differ dramatically. Your data appears to be far from smooth, which leads me to believe that obtaining a good approximation of the actual curve is going to be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried polynomial interpolation? Don't forget to sort by date before you do that.

```
data.interpolate(method='polynomial', order=2)
```

See [Link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) for more references

Comment: Yes i tried all the methods proposed by this function. My data is sorted. However, the methods are not efficient as they interpolate too smoothly the time series which then doesn't take account the past and moreover polynomial interpolation doesn't imply an ascending interpolation.

Comment: If interpolation is too smooth, I think you should try to set up a time series model to fill the gap.